# Newtonian Physics of a Trebuchet

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations

I am trying to make a simulation of a counterweight trebuchet, with a sling and a hinged counter-weigh, using Newtonian physics, by solving a set of simultaneous equations at each time step, then using some differential solving method, Heun's method or RK-4, to find the new positions.

I have taken some of my analysis from here: https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/trebuchet-physics.html, however we have only 4 equations for 6 unknowns. I attempted to use relative velocity and acceleration equations, which gave me enough equations to solve for the values, however the solutions don't make physical sense.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you can use this link to solve your problem.http://www.uphysicsc.com/2010-GM-B-210.pdf

Comment: this uses Lagrangian mechanics, which I understand is natural for this problem, however I am trying to use Newtonian physics to complete this as an exercise

Comment: https://jfuchs.hotell.kau.se/kurs/amek/prst/17_treb.pdf